# Can not install the CRAN packages "viridis", "Hmisc" on IBM Watson Studio R Environment Notebooks

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, cran, hmisc, watson-studio

I am trying to install the CRAN [Hmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package in an R Environment Notebook on IBM Watson Studio. But it repeatedly fails with the following Error:

```
install.packages('Hmisc')

also installing the dependencies ‘checkmate’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘Formula’, ‘latticeExtra’, ‘acepack’, ‘gridExtra’, ‘htmlTable’, ‘viridis’

Warning message in install.packages("Hmisc"):
“installation of package ‘viridis’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("Hmisc"):
“installation of package ‘Hmisc’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

I tried to separately install the `viridis` package and that also fails with the same error:

```
install.packages('viridis')

Warning message in install.packages("viridis"):
“installation of package ‘viridis’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In turns out to be an incorrect dependency management on `viridis`. It has a dependency over `viridisLite >= 0.2.0`. Latest `viridis` is expecting an object called `cividis` which was only added on the latest version of `viridisLite > 0.2.0`. DSX has `viridisLite==0.2.0` already installed. Hence, the install of `viridis` fails. So basically, explicitly installing a newer version of `viridisLite` solves the issue.

```
install.packages(c('viridisLite', 'Hmisc'))
```

TL;DR - Install latest `viridisLite` and then install `Hmisc`

Answer (score 1):

What I did was go down a version of the library using `devtools`:

```
require(devtools)
install_version('Hmisc',  version = "4.1-0")
```

Then I installed it again:

```
install.package('Hmisc')
```

You can then load the library `library('Hmisc')` and run `sessionInfo()` to see that you're running the latest version. It's a workaround and I don't know why it initially doesn't want to install. Perhaps it has something to do with R in DSX using version 3.3.2 and some libraries are missing? I haven't a clue.

Comment: R version on DSX Environment Notebooks is `3.4.2`. Checkout the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: It seems like the real issue is with installing `viridis` and not `Hmisc`. Updating the question accordingly

Comment: I checked out `sessionInfo()`, otherwise I would have said 3.4.2. Mine is R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31).

Comment: Are you sure that you are on an R-Environment notebook (its a new feature) and not on a Spark Service R Notebook?